# Export CSV in Shipping Rates doesn't work

Tags: magento2, csv, export

I have Magento 2.1.1 in production mode. I go to:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods**.

When I try to export the CSV example to upload the rathes, the system after 10 seconds redirect me to the home.

I tried to debug the problem but it's not any error apparently.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved:

**The Magento 2 sample package was not installed.**